# Accepting Nominations — Who should moderate this site?

Tags: discussion, moderation

Ideally Moderators are elected by the community, but until the community is large enough to hold a proper election, we will be appointing three provisional Moderators to fill those roles.

We need your help. Please nominate folks you would like to see become provisional moderators for this site. Your input will provide valuable insight to help us make our selections. You can read more about the process here: **[Moderators Pro Tempore](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/).**

### The Nomination Process:

- **Nominate a user** by posting an 'answer' below. Each nomination should be a separate answer. Use the template at the bottom of this post to complete your nomination.
- **Self nominations are encouraged.** This is a volunteer activity, so users should not feel obligated to accept these positions. A self-nomination is simply a way to say, "I am very much interested in this, so let my record speak for itself."
- **Tell us about the candidates.** Nominations can include links to other activities like Area 51 participation, participation in other sites, or any relevant thoughts/links that may help us make an informed decision.
- **Nominees!** Please indicate your acceptance by editing the answer to accept/decline the nomination. And please ensure your profile email is correct so we can contact you. Optionally, you are encouraged to write a bit about yourself following your acceptance.

  > I accept/decline this nomination.
  >
  > Hi, I am name/location/fun fact (all optional). I live in <location>, so I am generally active on this site from <time> to <time>. Some other things you may want to know about me are…

### Here is what we'll be looking for in a Moderator candidate:

We are looking for members who are deeply engaged in the community's development; members who:

- Have been consistently active during the earliest weeks of this site's creation
- Show an interest in their meta's community-building activities
- Lead by example, showing patience and respect for their fellow community members in everything they write
- Exhibit those intangible traits discussed in [**A Theory of Moderation**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

---

### Nomination Template

To nominate a candidate, copy and paste the text below as an answer and complete your nomination writeup:

> <a href="http://esperanto.stackexchange.com/users/**UserID**">
>   <img src="http://esperanto.stackexchange.com/users/flair/**UserID**.png"></a>
>   <a href="http://meta.esperanto.stackexchange.com/users/**UserID**">
>   <img src="http://meta.esperanto.stackexchange.com/users/flair/**UserID**.png"></a>
>   ###Notes:
>   This nominee would be a good choice because …

[image]

Answer (score 19):

[image]

[image]

---

## Esperanto

Saluton al ĉiuj, mi volas prezenti mian kandidatiĝon al la posteno de kontrolanto por la publika beta-version de Esperanto StackExchange.

Mia ĉefa celo estas helpi Esperanto-parolantojn. Mi rimarkis, ke ne ekzistas centra retejo por meti demandojn kaj respondojn en la saman lokon. Tio estas problemo, ĉar kiam iu homo respondas al demando, tiu homo ofte faras tion en iu loko kaŝita (ekzemple Facebook). Pro tio, la respondo ne estas facile trovebla por tiuj, kiuj havas la saman demandon.

Por solvi tiun problemon, mi aktive subtenis la projekton ĉe Area51, ĉar mi konstatis la efikecon de StackExchange por valorigi demandojn kaj respondojn. Mi faris [plurajn](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Iza5Gh8QNOE) [videojn](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2LbfQhtM2hA) pri la projekto en mia Jutuba kanalo por klarigi kio estas SE kaj por motivigi homojn. Aldone al tio, mi estas tre aktiva en la sociaj retejoj kie troviĝas Esperantistoj (ekzemple ĉe [Twitter](https://twitter.com/VanegeEsperanto), [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/user/Vanege/) kaj Facebook), kaj mi uzis mian influpovon tie por reklami la projekton kaj StackExchange.

Mi volas iĝi kontrolanto ĉar mi volas ke tiu retejo helpu kiel eble plej la Esperantistojn. Mi volas ke SE estu bonveniga loko por Esperantistoj, kaj ke ili uzu tiun retejon ĉiam kiam ili havas demandon kiu taŭgas. Mi certas ke StackExchange povas multe helpi la lernadon de Esperanto kaj de la Esperanta kulturo. Pro tio, mi volas zorgi pri la kvalito de tiu retejo, kaj helpi konstrui pontojn inter tiu retejo kaj la aliaj retejoj en Esperantujo.

---

## English

Hello everybody, I want to present my self-nomination to the role of moderator for the public beta version of Esperanto Language at StackExchange.

My main goal is to help Esperanto-speakers. I became aware that a central website for gathering questions and anwsers about Esperanto do not exist. This is a problem, because when someone answers to a question, he often does that in a hidden place of the Internet (Facebook for exemple). Because of this, the answer is not easy to find for the ones who have the same question.

To resolve this problem, I actively promoted the project at Area51, because I realised the efficiency of StackExchange to valorise questions and answers. I did [several](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Iza5Gh8QNOE) [videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2LbfQhtM2hA) about the project in my Youtube channel to explain what is StackExchange and to motivate people to help. Besides, I am very active in social media where Esperanto-speakers can be found (exemple: [Twitter](https://twitter.com/VanegeEsperanto), [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/user/Vanege/) kaj Facebook), and I used my influence there to promote the project and StackExchange.

I want to become moderator, because I want the website to help Esperantists as much as possible. I want SE to be a welcoming place to Esperantists and I want SE to become a habit for Esperantists when they have a question. I am convinced that SE can help the learning of Esperanto and its community a lot, that is why I want to actively care about the quality of this website. Ultimetely, I want to build a bridge between StackExchange and the Esperanto community.

Answer (score 10):

[image]
[image]
[image]

I have experience of moderating a Stack Exchange site since *Drupal Answers* beta phase. I am a 50K user on *Meta Stack Exchange*, the meta site for all the Stack Exchange network. Being also a 10K+ user in five sites (including two sites about English language), I understand perfectly how to use the tools made available for moderating a Stack Exchange site at any level.

Answer (score 10):

[image]

[image]

#### Notes:

I started learning Esperanto around 2001. I regularly attend Esperanto events and the language is a major part of my everyday life. I recently passed the CEFR exam at the C1 level and I believe I have a fairly good command of the language, but of course like everyone I am still constantly learning and improving. My native language is English and I have a working level of French.

I'm very excited about the Esperanto Stack Exchange because I think it is something that is severely lacking in the Esperanto community. There are several other places where people can ask questions but the useful information usually gets lost amongst the noise. That is why a site with Stack Exchange's voting system is essential and I want to do as much as possible to help it succeed.

I have a technical background as a computer programmer and I have been using StackOverflow for many years, although mostly in a purely passive way.

I am already trying to take an active role in helping to moderate the Esperanto site by flagging posts, commenting and taking part in the meta discussions. If I were to become a moderator I would hope to keep my interventions to a minimum by only acting on obvious spam or harmful posts. I would hope any action outside of that would come from a consensus from the community rather than the moderators enforcing their own opinions.

Answer (score 9):

[image]

[image]

[profile for kristan on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/6574146.png](http://stackexchange.com/users/)

I would like to offer to help moderate.

**Strengths:**

My strengths are mostly experience with the Esperanto language, and with editing in general. I learned Esperanto back in 2013, and volunteered as a language tutor on lernu.net for about a year, until the site got redesigned. I have a good grasp of Esperanto grammar and vocabulary, so I can easily tell if a suggested grammatical edit is an improvement or not, and see if unedited posts need editing of grammar or spelling (as well as discerning whether or not an answer regarding grammar or vocabulary is accurate). Also, I work as a proofreader (of English-language texts), so I can help improve English-language posts that have significant spelling or grammatical errors.

I am very enthusiastic about Esperanto and really want to help people learn it, by providing clear, accurate answers, and I'm very patient with learners because I so clearly remember being a beginner myself.

I have a little bit of experience with moderating, as I am an admin on the Toki Pona Taso group on Facebook, as well as a moderator of the Learn Lojban subreddit (irrelevant fact: "kristan" happens to be my Lojban name).

I was a supporter of this site on Area51, although I don't remember if I was there for the Definition phase, or just for Commitment, but I am very supportive of the site in either case.

Here are links to my profiles on [*lernu!*](http://lernu.net/en/uzanto/188231/profilo) and [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/user/christa627/), in case you want to see my history there.

**Weaknesses:**

I am relatively new to StackExchange (been here on and off for about a year), and am still not very well-versed in the logistics of it. But I am very willing to learn :-).

I am an old softie; I tend not to take action against anything that isn't outright spam. On the plus side, that keeps me from being an overbearing power-freak, on the minus side it may hinder me from being as effective in improving the site as I might be otherwise. But as there will be multiple mods, that may not be a huge problem.